# Get max record and min record together via MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Having a dataset like this:

```
id inv value
1  1   10
1  2   12
1  3   4
2  1   20
2  2   2
```

How to write a SQL to get the dataset, for each id, use the min inv record minus max inv record's value data, the dataset looks like below:

```
id delta_value min_inv max_inv
1    6           1       3
2    18          1       2
```

Please notice that max inv's value doesn't necessarily mean max value.

Comment: it helps if you tell us your table name and column types; best way is to just show the output of `show create table yourtablename` (as text, not an image).  also, what mysql version?

Comment: Please learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, delta_value, min(inv) min_inv, max(inv) max_inv
from (
    select
        id,
        first_value(value) over (partition by id order by inv)
        - first_value(value) over (partition by id order by inv desc) delta_value,
        inv
    from foo
) foo group by id, delta_value;
```

Comment: I would add that this only works on MySQL 8+ as it was the version that introduced windowing functions! +1.

Comment: Error: delta_value must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause

Comment: @hongchangfirst ah, added it to the group by.  that's needed if you have the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql mode set

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your MySQL version supports `window functions`, you could pick the `max` and `min` value per id, based on matching `max` and `min` inv per id. This works especially if you have multiple values per id per inv

```
select id, 
       max(value)-min(value) as delta_value,
       max(inv) as max_inv, 
       min(inv) as min_inv
from (select id, 
             inv, 
             case when inv = max(inv) over (partition by id) 
                    or inv = min(inv) over (partition by id) then value  end as value
           from your_table) t
group by id;
```

**[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/prmLXsLCZVU86aWP7K1G5K/5)**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a subset of your set to get desired values, this is Mysql < 8 compatible query. With MySql 8+ you can see answer provided by @ysth

```
select imm.id, 
       tmin.value-tmax.value as delta_value,
       imm.min_inv,
       imm.max_inv
  from (select id, 
               min(inv) min_inv, 
               max(inv) max_inv 
          from yourTable 
         group by id) imm 
        inner join yourTable tmin on tmin.id = imm.id
                                    and tmin.inv = imm.min_inv
        inner join yourTable tmax on tmax.id = imm.id
                                    and tmax.inv = imm.max_inv
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88a4d6/2

Answer (score 0):

If `inv` always starts from `1`, then conditional aggregation comes to mind:

```
select id,
       sum(case when inv = max_inv then value
                when inv = 1 then - value
           end),
       min(inv), max(inv)
from (select t.*,
             max(inv) over (partition by id) as max_inv
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

You can even do this without subqueries (although the performance is probably no better):

```
select distinct id,
       (first_value(value) over (partition by id order by inv desc) -
        first_value(value) over (partition by id order by inv asc)
       ) as diff,
       min(inv) over (partition by id),
       max(inv) over (partition by id)
        
from t;
```